# Runoff-style voting using Rails/ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, voting

I'm working on a website for a "runoff election"-style contest, i.e. voters can vote for multiple candidates, but voters can only vote once for any individual candidate.

My models are:

- candidate
- voter
- vote

Currently, I'm using the [Cantor pairing function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) to create generate a unique integer/token for each vote, based on the candidate ID and voter ID. My vote model validates the uniqueness of this token, effectively preventing folks from voting more than once for a given candidate.

Even though my code works really well, I know there must be a way to use ActiveRecord associations and bypass the math, but I'm pretty new to Rails -- any input/discussion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just validate the uniqueness of the `voter_id` and `candidate_id` in the `Vote` table?

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_uniqueness_of :voter_id, scope: :candidate_id

end
```

You should add an index to the DB too:

```
add_index "votes", ["voter_id", "candidate_id"], unique: true
```

Comment: This works perfectly; I had no idea it was this straightforward! Thanks!

Comment: No problem! It would be great if you could accept my answer, then I can get some delicious SO points that I can use to buy my family food.